# Would it be more appropriate to use negative Binomial regression instead of Poisson regression if my sample variance is greater than my sample mean?

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

My response variable $y_i$ denotes the number of articles produced by journalist $i$ in the  last two years. It is a count variable with fixed exposure hence why I chose to use Poisson regression.

I have a dataset containing the number of articles produced by numerous different journalists and I also have values of other variables (my predictor variables).

I have calculated the sample mean and sample variance of the variable $y$, and the sample variance is nearly double (over-dispersion). Is this a good enough reason for me to use negative Binomial regression? Should I consider anything else? The deviance of the model also drops by a noticeable amount when I use NB over Poisson.

This is my first time considering using a negative Binomial regression so I apologise if the question is very basic.

Comment: Welcome to our site. The sample variance is large because it incorporates variation among the predictor variables, too: thus, it is inappropriate for selecting the model.  Consider applying what you initially thought was a good model and conducting diagnostic analyses on its *residuals:* that is what matters.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your response but I am not convinced by that explanation. I am only looking at the sample variance and mean of the number of articles produced; I do not consider the predictors when I do this.

Comment: To expound on @whuber's point, over-dispersion in regression analysis refers to the distribution of the response *within* predictors- whereas it sounds like you've considered the distribution of the response *across* predictors.

Comment: @khol Interesting. How could I correctly test for over-dispersion, given a glm?

Answer (score 2):

Formally, i don't think you can go off your raw sample variance and mean, because the distribution is conditional i.e. $Y|X \thicksim P(\lambda)$

I can be totally wrong on the first point, so someone correct me. But generally as a rule of thumb test for overdispersion is to fit your model and divide the residual deviance by the residual degrees of freedom; if it's much larger than 1 then it's probably overdispersed.

A more formal hypothesis test is to simply test if the negative binomial fits better. That is, the Poisson is the Negative Binomial when $k \rightarrow 0$. So, we are actually testing if

$H_0: k = 0$ and $H_1: k > 0$

This can be tested using the log likelihood ratio test:

$LR=2(\ell_{NB}-\ell_p)$ which is distributed $\chi_p^2$ where $p$ is the number of parameters. Only tricky thing is the cutoff is at $\alpha=0.1$ instead of $0.05$ because the distribution of LR has a mass of $0.5$ at $k=0$ and a half-$\chi_p^2$ distribution above zero. Basically just fit two models and use the log likelihood reatio test to compare their deviances.

In `R`, you can either compute it by hand using the `logLik` to pull out the loglikelihoods and substituting into the formmula and then looking up the chi squared criitical value at 0.1. Or, the `pscl` package has a `odTest` command to test this for you. See more [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/pscl/man/odTest.html), but I haven't tried that one myself.